# Underline comes while writing in textbox

Tags: html, css

I am new to html/css, I have a textbox while writing an underline comes below the words.once the focus goes off then goes automatically.I want to remove that underline while typing.

I have used `text-decoration: none;`
and `spellcheck="false"`

but its not working.

my snippet

```
 <input  type="text" spellcheck="false" class="text-line"  id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
```

I am also attaching the image.

[image: here]

css

```
.text-line {
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 15%;
    color: #000000;
    outline: none;
    outline-style: none;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: solid #eeeeee 1px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 3px 5px;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a http://www.jsfiddle.net for this

Comment: Show us the CSS for class `text-line`

Comment: i think the line was becase of the `class="text-line"`. which could have the css that makes the underline. try checking

Comment: i tried it in jsfiddle its working fine, dont know why in mobile application its not working

Comment: it worked  adding autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked adding `autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off"`
in html.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

There are several cases:

1. That class *text-line* could have declared a selector :focus that puts an underline to your text
2. The input text could have binded a javascript event that puts an underline to your text when the input is in focus, and remove it when it is not